# How to solve subversion tree conflict: branch removed a directory and trunk changed a file there

Tags: svn, tree-conflict

1) I have a trunk and created a branch from it.

2) The trunk contains a directory A, in the branch this directory was renamed to B.

3) Now in the trunk we accidently made a change to a file F in A.

4) Reintegrating the branch generates a tree conflict

5) Beeing clever I reverted the changes to file F in the trunk - however this was not the solution since during the merger subversion still tries to execute the changes and then reverts them. Which still leads to the conflict.

Question-Part A: What is the correct solution to handle this situation? Just accept the conflict an handle it manually?

Question-Part B: Is subversion generally not able to merge files, if the file is in a directory that has been renamed in a branch?

(I am using Subversion 1.6 and Tortoise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question A: `svn resolve --accept=working` and sort it out manually, as you already said.

Question B: No it can't. If anybody knows a solution I'm eager to learn it.

You may have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122820/tortoisesvn-approaches-to-resolve-tree-conflicts/4127931#4127931) which tackles tree conflicts as well.